# Cleaning log files on Solaris for a service manifest

Tags: logging, solaris, log-files, smartos

I have a service manifest on Solaris (Smart OS actually) and I would like to periodically clean its log files either automatically or manually without shutting down the server.

My log is here:

```
/var/svc/log/site-myapp-joyent-smartos-node-service-manifest-1:default.log
```

Is there a way to either clean this, limit its size, or move it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use logadm to rotate the logs for you. On the latest base image (13.1.0) there is a default logadm entry for rotating SMF logs (check the /etc/logadm.conf file):

```
smf_logs -C 3 -c -s 1m /var/svc/log/*.log
```

That entry will rotate the SMF service logs whenever they hit 1m in size (-s 1m), only keep 3 versions after each rotation (-C 3) and rotate the log by copying the original log file then truncating it to zero (-c). The nice thing about the above is that it's a pattern based logadm definition, so you can run it manually with:

```
logadm smf_logs
```

There is a crontab entry (under the root user) on the base 13.1.0 image to run logadm once per hour.

```
10 * * * * /usr/sbin/logadm
```

An hourly cron is good for size based rotation and helps keep things in check if some logs tend to grow pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks!  Awesome detail.  This is exactly what I needed :)  Can you clarify the "10 * * * * /usr/sbin/logadm"  How do I check what the cronjob is set at (frequency) and how do I change it?

Comment: That will run the /usr/sbin/logadm command every hour, at 10 minutes past the hour.  `man crontab` and `man cron`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing a script then create a cron job to run the script periodically.

Comment: Yes, but can I archive the file (or chop it head -n 5000) while the manifest is running and writing to the file?

Comment: If the file is being written to, you can't move the file. In that case, you need to copy the contents and then zero the file.

Comment: How do I zero a file being written to?

Answer (score -2):

any open file can be zeroised with   >file.name

deleteing the open file will not free the filestore